# Посчитать количество элементов в словаре с вложениями

Tags: python, dict

Имеется словарь с различными уровнями вложения (где-то на 2 уровня глубже, где-то на 3 или 4)

```
{'a': {'s': {...}, 't': {...}}, 'b': {'q': {...}, 'y': {...}, 'k': {...}}, ['1', '2', '3'...], 'c': {'c': {...}, 'm': {...}}}
```

Как наиболее оптимально перебрать весь словарь и посчитать количество отдельных элементов, чтобы не писать слишком много циклов.

Конечным значением может быть либо список (добавлять длину списка), либо строка (добавлять 1 элемент)

Пока что вижу такую реализацию:

```
c = 0
for k in all_val.keys():
    if type(all_val[k]) == list:
        c += len(all_val[k])
    elif type(all_val[k]) == str:
        c += 1
    else:
        for k2 in all_val[k]:
            if type(all_val[k][k2]) == list:
                c += len(all_val[k][k2])
            elif type(all_val[k][k2]) == str:
                c += 1
            else:
                for k3 in all_val[k][k2]:
                    if type(all_val[k][k2][k3]) == list:
                        c += len(all_val[k][k2][k3])
                    elif type(all_val[k][k2][k3]) == str:
                        c += 1
                    else:
                        for k4 in all_val[k][k2][k3]:
                            if type(all_val[k][k2][k3][k4]) == list:
                                c += len(all_val[k][k2][k3][k4])
                            elif type(all_val[k][k2][k3][k4]) == str:
                                c += 1
```

Comment: воспользуйтесь рекурсией

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете рекурсивно обойти весь словарь. Вот возможный пример решения. Функция пройдется по всем уровням вложений и посчитает количество элементов в Вашем словаре.

```python
def count_elements(my_dict):
    c = 0
    for v in my_dict.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            c += count_elements(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            c += len(v)
        elif isinstance(v, str):
            c += 1
    return c
```

```python
my_dict = {'a': {'s': {...}, 't': {...}}, 'b': {'q': {...}, 'y': {...}, 'k': {...}}, ['1', '2', '3'...], 'c': {'c': {...}, 'm': {...}}}
c = count_elements(my_dict)
print(c)
```